# How to write the databinder into the image tag in datalist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

I'm using the img tag but i got the error. I know this is simple error. But i don't know. 
This is error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a property with 
the name 'image'.
```

This is my code:

```
<img src='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"image")) %>' 
     id="Img" alt="Image Name" />
```

Comment: Could you post the full tag starting from < to />

Comment: To get better response from this site, please post Properly formatted question with necessary details to describe your problem. you should read this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. if your questions ware continuously down voted then  you may not able to post in this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your data-source. Check the Data-Source means in the Select Query in Database or In-Line Query from which you are filling the DataTable or DataSet. it must include **Image** Column.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory you don't have anything with name `image` in your data-source.

The problem with your data-source. There must be a property name `image` in you data-source.